# Как можно остановить все потоки приложения?

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, c#

Можно ли в C# остановить вообше все порождённые потоки прилождения? То есть если приложения создаёт 2 потока, а каждый из них создаёт ещё по одному потоку. Можно ли в таком случае остановить все потоки?

Answer (score 3):

1. Порождая поток, запоминать его в какой-нибудь глобальный список.
2. Потом обойти этот список и для каждого потока вызвать метод Abort.
3. Получить список выполняющихся потоков через стандартный API дотнета нельзя. Можно получить список потоков ОС, но не совпадает со списком управляемых потоков.

Comment: Да, спасибо, появилась одна идейка с использованием List<Thread>, надо попробовать:)

Answer (score 0):

Можно перебрать все потоки процесса и поубивать их. Перебрать все потоки процесса можно с помощью функций CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, Thread32First, Thread32Next.
Вот [здесь есть примерчик](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686852%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Вообще-то Ваш пример на C / C++, а не на C#

Answer (score 0):

NtSuspendProcess. Для текущего процесса будет деадлок.

Answer (score 0):

Завершить текущий процесс. При его завершении все его потоки будут остановлены.

Comment: При завершении процесса все треды завершаются.

Comment: @Indy именно это и требуется по вопросу, и Вы мой ответ только повторили.

Comment: @IAZ: наверное, Indy знает о какой-то тайной разнице между тредами и потоками.